# Can't figure out the errors in this pl/ql procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to get the average score from the database and then grade each student in accordance to their average grade.

```
PROCEDURE avge (stu_id IN NUMBER, z OUT VARCHAR2, lv_avg OUT NUMBER) 
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT AVG(SCORE)
    into lv_avg
    FROM GRADE
   WHERE STUDENT_ID = stu_id;

  IF (lv_avg BETWEEN 90 AND 100) THEN
     z := 'A';
  ELSIF (lv_avg BETWEEN 80 AND 90) THEN
     z := 'B';
  ELSIF (lv_avg < 80) THEN
     z := 'C';
  END IF; 
END;
```

These are the errors that pop up are:

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 22:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "STU_ID": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'LV_AVG' must be declared
```

Comment: This procedure is perfectly fine. What exactly are you executing? The error looks like you're executing only the BEGIN .. END; block of this procedure

Comment: I am executing the above procedure to implement it into another pl/sql code.

Comment: You can use "student_id" as a parameter if you prefix your use of it in SQL with the procedure name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PL/SQL doesn't require brackets around `if` expressions, because they are already terminated with `then`, so the ones in your code are redundant.

`case` can avoid some repetition of `z :=`. I would also choose a more descriptive parameter name than `z` - and as `lv_avg` is neither a local variable nor anything to do with luncheon vouchers, I would not prefix it with `lv_`.

Also all of your keywords except `into` seem to be in uppercase. Why is that?

I would use something like this:

```
create or replace procedure avge
    ( p_student_id  in  grade.student_id%type
    , p_out_grade   out varchar2
    , p_out_avg     out grade.score%type )
is
begin
    select avg(score) into p_out_avg
    from   grade
    where  student_id = p_student_id;

    p_out_grade :=
        case
            when p_out_avg between 90 and 100 then 'A'
            when p_out_avg between 80 and  90 then 'B'
            when p_out_avg < 80 then 'C'
        end;
end avge;
```

Comment: So is `if ((((lv_avg between 90 and 100)))) then`. My point is that any brackets around the conditional expression are redundant. The OP may be thinking of other languages that do not have a `then` keyword.

Comment: OK. Updated. Since the OP is learning PL/SQL I didn't want to leave the impression that brackets were some kind of optional syntax which he might feel was good practice to write in full. The brackets are only valid because they are allowed around any expression.

Comment: Never knew IF cannot have parenthesis. Yes, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Well, you can put brackets in a lot of places that are not required. [The syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS386) does not specify any brackets after `if` but if you include them it will still compile (they are ignored).

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to add the `create or replace` while running it on pls/ql command window

```
Create or replace PROCEDURE avge (stu_id IN NUMBER, z OUT VARCHAR2, lv_avg OUT NUMBER) 
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT AVG(SCORE)
    into lv_avg
    FROM GRADE
   WHERE STUDENT_ID = stu_id;

  IF (lv_avg BETWEEN 90 AND 100) THEN
     z := 'A';
  ELSIF (lv_avg BETWEEN 80 AND 90) THEN
     z := 'B';
  ELSIF (lv_avg < 80) THEN
     z := 'C';
  END IF; 
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE avge(stu_id IN INTEGER,z OUT CHAR,lv_avg OUT DECIMAL) AS
BEGIN
  SELECT AVG(score) INTO lv_avg FROM grade WHERE student_id=stu_id;
  IF (lv_avg BETWEEN 90 AND 100) THEN z:='A';
  ELSIF (lv_avg BETWEEN 80 AND 90) THEN z:='B';
  ELSE z:='C';
  END IF; 
END;
/
```

Comment: You can use between. This is elsif so first if catches [90-100] second [80;90) and third rest.

Comment: This does something different from the OP procedure

Comment: @Kacper, yes, you're right, BETWEEN can be used in this case. I'm used to pivoting with CASE WHEN where this principle cannot be used.

Comment: Yes in case instruction it would make a problem.